# Can I import a package from a monorepo in another repository?

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook, monorepo, lerna

I have a `create-react-app` and a `storybook` packages set up in a `lerna` monorepo. Now I want to use the components I made in the `storybook` package in an entirely new repo.

I've tried using `npm install git://github.com/username/repo.git`, which works. However, the problem is I do not want to download both packages.

Generally, is there a way to import just one package from a monorepo? Additionally, would this be considered good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Are you solve this, i'll to do same. Install private package in monorepo via git urls